# Explorer for Private Blockchain with Ganache

Tags: private-blockchain, ganache, explorers

I set up a private blockchain with ganache in the server. Now I want to view the transactions like in the public blockchain explorer. Locally I use Ganache GUI where I can actually track down everything. How can I do the same for my private blockchain?

Comment: Did you try running ganache gui in the server? It should work the same as local.

Comment: Not yet. I think I should give a try

Comment: Can you guide how do I setup Ganache GUI and view it in the browser?

Answer (score 6):

Ethernal (https://tryethernal.com/) is an open-source block explorer for private EVM-based chains. You'll have the same feature as Etherscan or Ganache UI but you can connect it to any chain.

(I am the developer of this project)

Comment: How does this differ re the OP's question from using Ganache?

Comment: @TheRenaissance, You can only use Ganache UI with the chain started by Ganache UI, you can't use it with another chain (like a ganache-cli one running locally, or a remote one).
From what I understood, this is what OP wants to do, Ethernal is a way to do this.

Comment: Can you explore local blockchain with it?

Comment: @PlumillonForge yes it's possible

Comment: not showing blocks

Comment: @DavidFischer, feel free to reach out through Discord or the contact form on the website, happy to help you debug that

Comment: @Antoine I tested ethernal out and it works great!

Answer (score 5):

You are able to use [Blockscout](https://github.com/blockscout/blockscout) as a block explorer for `ganache-cli`.

To do a local trial run I recommend using [Blockscout via Docker](https://docs.blockscout.com/for-developers/information-and-settings/docker-integration-local-use-only):

1. Start a local chain via `ganache-cli`
2. Clone [Blockscout](https://github.com/blockscout/blockscout) and change to `docker`
3. Run (assuming you are on macOS)

   ```
   COIN=ETH \
   ETHEREUM_JSONRPC_VARIANT=ganache \
   ETHEREUM_JSONRPC_HTTP_URL=http://host.docker.internal:8545 \
   ETHEREUM_JSONRPC_WS_URL=ws://host.docker.internal:8545 \
   make start
   ```

   - the first build takes a lot of time (about 15m on my machine)
   - consecutive starts are much faster
4. Visit `http://localhost:4000`

You are able to permanently set up Blockscout by following their [(manual) install doc](https://docs.blockscout.com/for-developers/manual-deployment).

Comment: way too many requirements, we just want a simple explorer

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [explorer from etherparty](https://github.com/etherparty/explorer).

1. you can change the host and port from here as today's version.
   app/app.js Line no: 30.

Comment: works perfectly thanks!